# Can I test Android on the Moto X?

Tags: android

I recently bought a Moto X and was following the online instructions for setting it up to test my android code. I installed the USB drivers and got to the place where it tells me that the phone is unlockable. I quickly returned the phone at this point before activating it and subsequently porting my number over.

Can I test code on the Moto X specifically even if it is NOT bootloader unlockable? Is this the case for all android devices?

Unfortunately I don't know anyone that is a developer or even anyone that owns a Droid phone that I could experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to unlock bootloader to test your Android applications. Please refer to [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) for more information regarding setting up any Android device for testing. Following is the relevant part quoted for your information:

> You can use any Android-powered device as an environment for running, debugging, and testing your applications. The tools included in the SDK make it easy to install and run your application on the device each time you compile.

This is a general answer, not specific to Moto X. I do not see any reason why it should not apply to Moto X.